# how to estimate this expression (comes from probability) asymptotically?

Tags: probability, asymptotics, estimation

Consider
$$(n-1)\exp\{(n-1)(\frac{1}{2}-p(n))\}(2p(n))^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

where $n$ is positive integer, $p(n)$ is a function of $n$ that is undefined. This expression in my context represents a probability of a random event, I want it to be 'small'.

My question is, under which condition of $p(n)$ is the above expression decreasingly (maybe exponentially decreasing) approaching $0$ when $n$ grows?

I have no experience of dealing with asymptotics, and here is what I tried:
Assume $p(n)=n^\alpha$ (though I think this is too loose..)
$$=(n-1)n^{\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{2}}e^{\frac{1}{2}(-2n^{\alpha+1}+2n^\alpha+n-1)}2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\leq (n-1)n^{\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{2}}e^{\frac{1}{2}(-2n^{\alpha+1}+2n^\alpha+n-1)}e^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=(n-1)n^{\frac{\alpha(n-1)}{2}}e^{-n^{\alpha+1}+n^\alpha+n-1}$$

Many thanks for hints.

Comment: What is $e()$ ? Also $t=-\frac{(n-1)\delta}{2}$ would then actually be $t(n)=-\frac{(n-1)\delta(n)}{2}$?

Comment: @leonbloy sorry! $e()$ is $\exp()$. for the second questions, yes

Comment: The expression is really ugly. You should symplify and format it. To start with, use $m=n-1$ and $\beta = \delta/2$, etc

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for the suggestion. I found there is an error in the expression thus I modified it, to make sure that it is correct and simplified as much as I could.